# Can I show filter text disabled?

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2

I want to Disable filter option.

Like this image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filterInputOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$filterInputOptions-detail) :

```
[
  'attribute' => 'name',
  'value' => 'value',
  'filterInputOptions' => ['disabled' => true]
],
```